# OpenJDK shows intermittent performance and UI issues

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm receiving following message inside of `Event Log` window whenever I'm launching Android Studio:

```
OpenJDK shows intermittent performance and UI issues. We recommend using the Oracle JRE/JDK
```

In order to run Android Studio, I was asked to install Java 1.7+, which  I did:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ rpm -q jdk1.8.0_25-1.8.0_25-fcs
jdk1.8.0_25-1.8.0_25-fcs.x86_64
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

I'm using following:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core) 
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ uname -a
Linux wcmisdlin02.XXX.org 3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 18 14:09:13 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

How can I either force or "re point" `Android Studio` to use Oracle JDK instead of OpenJDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is to set the `STUDIO_JDK` environment variable before launching.

```
export STUDIO_JDK=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25-1.8.0_25-fcs.x86_64
./studio.sh
```

replacing `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25-1.8.0_25-fcs.x86_64` with the path of your jdk installation

Reference: [Configuring Android Studio: IDE & VM Options, JDK, etc - Android Tools Project Site](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration)

Comment: Hows about some upvote love?